# How to comment the typeparam of an Action?

Tags: c#, comments

With the following Action method, what is the right way to describe the `bool` in a comment?

```
public class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        Title = Strings.app_title;

        // here the Action gets injected into the constructor of the master page
        var master = new MainMenu(OnToggleRequest());
        var detail = new NavigationPage(new ModulePage { Title = Strings.app_title });

        Master = master;
        Detail = detail;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Toggles the Navigation Drawer
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An Action<bool?> where bool indicates if the Navigation Drawer Should Be Presented</returns>
    /// <remarks>If the bool is null, then the Navigation Drawer state will simply be toggled</remarks>
    private Action<bool?> OnToggleRequest()
    {
        return shouldBePresented =>
        {
            if (shouldBePresented == null)
            {
                // just switch it
                IsPresented = !IsPresented;
            }
            else
            {
                // manually set it
                IsPresented = (bool)shouldBePresented;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I usually would just do `Action<bool?>`. I mean that's what it returns, not `Action`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend to describe return value type and its parameters in comments. That is duplication of information which already present in code. Instead describe *what* returned value means.

Unfortunately I was not able to find any documented .NET method which returns Action for good sample of comment. Usually MSDN they just says something *Type: System.Action* when it describes such type of return value. Which looks like generated documentation to me.

Back to your case. It's hard to write good and short comment which explains purpose of method, if you don't know it's purpose. First attempt could look like

```
/// <returns>Callback for setting whether navigation drawer should present</returns>
/// <remarks>Pass true to callback to enable drawler, false to disable drawler, or null to toggle current setting.</remarks>
private Action<bool?> OnToggleRequest()
```

Long and complex comments for me like a smell, actually almost any comment is a smell :). If you can't explain what method is doing, then probably it's doing too many things, or it's unclear what method is doing. I see that you pass `null` to toggle value of IsPresented flag. For me passing `null` is very unclear. Instead of hiding explanation inside your method, and writing comment (which would not be accessible at the point where you invoke action), I would have property, and nice self-descriptive method:

```
public bool IsDrawlerEnabled { get; set; }

public void ToggleDrawler()
{
    IsDrawlerEnabled = !IsDrawlerEnabled;
}
```

It's not the best name yet, but much better than `toggleRequest(null)`.

Comment: yeah, that's what I mean. I edited the question, with a better comment. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: if I don't describe the return value in the comment, then when I try to utilize the method, I have no idea what the bool is used for.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell hold on, I'll give you an example of good comment

Comment: @ChaseFlorell sorry was busy a little. Can you describe intent of this method? It's hard to explain purpose of something, if you don't know what that thing doing :) Why you need this callback?

Comment: The purpose is simple. I need to be able to toggle a navigation panel located in a MasterDetailPage from within the Master page. Therefore I need to pass the `OnToggleRequest` Action to the constructor of the `Master` page. This is a Xamarin.Forms application. As for `IsPresented`, it's part of the X.F framework, and I don't have control over it's name.

Comment: Basically the action get's invoked in a separate class, and I don't want to make it a Public Static.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell sorry, I'm not aware of Xamarin development and its details. But I hope you've got the idea. You should not describe type of returned value - it's clear from code. Btw I didn't suggest to make something public static

Answer (score 0):

"Flag indicating whether X should be presented or not"